# Concatenate Two Tables

Tags: sql, t-sql, concatenation

I have two tables listed below, table ccms_all_users and table event in which I need to combine to get one output.

```
TABLE CCMS_ALL_USERS
---------------------------------
| CCMS_ID | FIRST NAME |LAST NAME
---------------------------------
| 110     | JEFF       |WOOD
| 111     | MICHAEL    |JOHNSON
| 112     | HARRY      |LEE
---------------------------------

Table EVENT:
-----------------------
| MEMBER_ID | CCMS_ID |
-----------------------
| 001       | 110     |
| 002       | 111     |
| 003       | 112     |
-----------------------
```

I would like the desired output as listed below but I am unsure how to use the concatenate function and what kind of join statement that I need to use.

I need to convert the actual ID to the First and Last Name of the user.

```
MY DESIRED OUTPUT
------------------------------------
| MEMBER_ID | CCMS_ID (Alias as Event Manager)                          
------------------------------------
| 001       | JEFF WOOD            |
| 002       | MICHAEL JOHSON       |
| 003       | HARRY LEE            |
```

How would I do this in sql using the concat function and joins?

Answer (score 2):

```
 SELECT e.MEMBER_ID,
        c.[FIRST NAME] + ' ' + c.[LAST NAME] 'Event Manager'
   FROM EVENT e
        INNER JOIN CCMS_ALL_USERS c ON e.CCMS_ID = c.CCMS_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query

```
 SELECT Member_ID,
        [First Name] + ' ' + [Last Name] as CCMS_ID
   FROM [EVENT] 
        JOIN [CCMS_ALL_USERS] ON [CCMS_ALL_USERS].[CCMS_ID] = [EVENT].[CCMS_ID]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT e.MEMBER_ID,
        u.[FIRST NAME] + ' ' + u.[LAST NAME] 'Event Manager'
   FROM EVENT e
        INNER JOIN CCMS_ALL_USERS u
  USING (CCMS_ID)
```